# python переносит цифры при записи в файл

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, текстовые-файлы

в общем на вход подается такая строка 7789004508685868=829 на выходе должна быть такая
`7789009392043512=00127229560000000`. А получается такая 00000007789000271516306=4912722957

Код:

```
f=open('cards.txt','r')
fwrite=open('dumps.txt','w')
for line in f:
    if "=" in line:
        card_info=line.split('=')
    elif ":" in line:
        card_info=line.split(':')
    
    if card_info[0][6:8]=='93':
        fwrite.write(card_info[0]+f"=0012722{card_info[1]}0000000")
    else:
        fwrite.write(card_info[0]+f"=4912722{card_info[1]}0000000")
```

Comment: Подправьте, если неправильно описал результат :)

Answer (score 2):

Дело в том, что в `line` будет символ перевода строки т.е. `\n` или `\n\r`, при итерировании файлового объекта. Можно или удалять справа те символы, или воспользоваться методом `readlines`

Когда вы разделили `line`, символ перевода строки попал `card_info[1]`

Я бы удалял справа символы перевода строки, а при записи в файл добавлял их:

```
f = open('cards.txt')
fwrite = open('dumps.txt', 'w')
for line in f:
    line = line.rstrip('\r\n')
    if "=" in line:
        card_info = line.split('=')
    elif ":" in line:
        card_info = line.split(':')
    
    if card_info[0][6:8] == '93':
        fwrite.write(f"{card_info[0]}=0012722{card_info[1]}0000000\n")
    else:
        fwrite.write(f"{card_info[0]}=4912722{card_info[1]}0000000\n")
```

**PS.**
Я бы сократил условие до:

```
    prefix = '0012722' if card_info[0][6:8] == '93' else '4912722'
    fwrite.write(f"{card_info[0]}={prefix}{card_info[1]}0000000\n")
```